# How to make debug page in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have set mode in .env file as: `APP_DEBUG = false;`

Now when error is happen it shows empty page with header: "Error".
How to make separated page for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a template in the views/error folder with name after the error code you want it to handle see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#custom-http-error-pages

Answer (score 1):

You can create Blade templates for specific HTTP error codes in `resources/views/errors/xxx.blade.php`. For instance you can make `resources/views/errors/500.blade.php` for Internal Server Errors or `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` for instances where a page can not be found. More here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#custom-http-error-pages